# p:treeNode: Custom Icons for custom TreeNode Types

Tags: primefaces, tree, icons, treenode

I'm running Primefaces 5.3.10, Mojarra 2.2.13, Java8 and Tomcat8.

I wanted to have a primefaces Tree with different types of TreeNodes. Each type of TreeNode should be rendered with a corresponding custom icon.

I studied a few examples on the web but couldn't find a working solution.

I have a java class TreeModel.java which offers a TreeNode:

```
public class TreeModel {

    TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);

    public TreeNode getRoot(){
        return root;
    }

    public void populizeTree(){
        TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode("customType1", "nodeName", root);
        TreeNode subNode = new DefaultTreeNode("customType2", "subNodeName", node);
        TreeNode subNode2 = new DefaultTreeNode("customType3", "subNode2Name", node);
    }
}
```

And a CustomTree.xhtml which describes my tree:

```
<p:tree value="#{TreeModel.root}" 
     var="node" 
     highlight="true"
     dynamic="true"
     selectionMode="single"
     id="modultree"
     style="width: 980px;">
      <p:treeNode type="customType1" icon="icon-modul">
          <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
      </p:treeNode>
      <p:treeNode type="customTyp2" icon="icon-konto">
          <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
      </p:treeNode>
      <p:treeNode type="customType3" icon="icon-exam">
          <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
      </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

In order to display different icons for the different TreeNode types i also created css-file named TreeNode.css:

```
.icon-modul {
    background: transparent url("#{resource['images:hio-modul.png']}")!important;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

.icon-konto {
    background: transparent url("#{resource['images:hio-konto.png']}")!important;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

.icon-exam {
    background: transparent url("#{resource['images:hio-pruefung.png']}")!important;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

and also placed the png-files in the directory /myApp/resources/images/.

I tried a few variations but either way the custom icon will not be rendered.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have a mistake in icon="SOME_CSS", i suggest to use StyleClass="SOME_CSS".

Comment: I'm sure you can provide waaaay more info then 'the custom icon will not be rendered'... the browser developertool is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

Kukeltje's hint solved my problem.
Using Firebug I can see, that the the css should be like

```
.ui-widget-content .icon-exam {
    background-image: url("../images/hio-pruefung.png") !important;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

I can't find a way to reference the image with the syntax:
url("#{resource['images:hio-pruefung.png']}")